# Converting SQL to Sybase dialect

Tags: sql-server-2008, sybase

The query is

```
Select id from TableA 
where typ_cd="NT"
 and id not in
( select id from TableA where typ_cd="BB")
```

I need to find those id's  whose type_cd ="NT" and compare those id's with the same table which are not present  for  type_cd="BB" .I pretty confused why the above query is not returning the correct values.

Edit: -I'm referencing the same table and there are no null values for the column ID

Please let me know how can i achieve the same result in sql server so that i can try to write an equivalent query in sybase

```
 TableA

id typ_cd
 1   NT
 1   BB
 3   NT
 4   NT
 4   BB
```

I need the id=1 as the `result` since the id=1 is present for typ_cd=NT but not for typ_cd=BB
But at present with the above query im getting null in sybase

Comment: Is that the sample of what you get or what you want? Can you make sure both are in the question. Also can you tell us if the data and structure of the tables on the two database is the same. Are there nulls etc?

Comment: @PreetSangha : My mistake .The query shown above is correct and even urs . It was just that  for all the rows having type_cd =NT there was matching rows for the type_cd=BB but it not vice versa .

Comment: Based on the data only 3 should come and not 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the double quotes with single quotes.

```
Select id from TableA 
where typ_cd='NT'
 and id not in
( select id from TableA where typ_cd='BB')
```

Comment: The query which i have posted is for Sybase .It works for both double and single quotes but unfortunately its not returning me the correct rows in sybase